# How to parse json file, where keys start with '--' characters (dash)

Tags: json, jq

I have below JSON file and would like to update the values of these keys `--resType` and `--LogLevel` using `jq`.

```
{
    "--resType": "FILE",
    "--LogLevel": "INFO"
}
```

To do that, I am using below command.

```
./jq .--resType=Test config.json>test.json
```

But, I see an error that says

> "jq: error: Test/0 is not defined at , line 1:".
>
> "jq: 2 compile errors"

Comment: You do a special quote around the keys to let it to be understood as a valid key name `jq '."--resType"' config.json` or another way with the square braces `[..]` as `jq '.["--resType"]' config.json`

Comment: ./jq '."--resType"'=\"Test\" config.json >test.json  worked for me. Thank you.